# Fetch something from steam api

Tags: php, api, steam

I'm working on a PHP script and I want it to fetch this from steam api:
[Steam api example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6oGz.png)

This is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
      
<head>
    <title>
        Test
    </title>
</head>
  
<body style="text-align:center;">

    <form method="post">
<input type="submit" value="OK" name="kk"/> 
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['kk'])) {
    $json = file_get_contents('https://api.steampowered.com/ICSGOServers_730/GetGameServersStatus/v1/?key=STEAM API KEY HERE');
    $obj = json_decode($json);
    echo $obj->result;
}
?>
     
</head>
  
</html>
```

How can I fetch it?

Comment: What is the question here? You are using `file_get_contents`, does it not `fetch` the json response (like in the image). If not what are the errors

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\status.php:20 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\status.php on line 20

Comment: `var_dump($object)` and take a look at the contents. Obviously you replaced `key=STEAM API KEY HERE` with your actual api key...

Comment: Done, what about now?

Comment: It returned something with the api, but its confuse

Comment: This is what returned: https://pastebin.com/Ap5kLVqq

Comment: Were you ever able to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to echo an stdClass as per your comments. That is why the error.

You can access the data (marked in red in the attached image ) like this

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['kk'])) {
    $json = file_get_contents('https://api.steampowered.com/ICSGOServers_730/GetGameServersStatus/v1/?key=STEAM API KEY HERE');
    $obj = json_decode($json);
    echo $obj->result->services->SessionsLogon;
    echo $obj->result->services->SteamCommunity;
    echo $obj->result->services->IEconItems;
}
```

If you are more comfortable with arrays instead of stdClass you can use `$obj = json_decode($json, true)` and access the elements with `echo $obj['result']['services']['SessionsLogon']` etc.

To get a human readable output of the stdClass or the array you should use `pre` and `print_r` instead of just `var_dump`. For eg. `echo '<pre>' . print_r($obj, true) . '</pre>';`